# C++ - Best viable function; array-to-pointer decay isn't conversion?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, implicit-conversion, overloading

In my interpretation of [these overload rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function), the code sample below should use the template method, as `void foo(const char (& a)[Size])` does not require any conversion when called by `const char[13]`. However, the compiler evidently prefer to convert `a` to `const char*`, which I believe would break this rule:

1. there is at least one argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2

Am I thinking about conversions in the wrong way? Code sample in question:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t Size>
void foo(const char (& a)[Size])
{
    std::cout << a << " (array [" << Size << "])\n";
}
void foo(const char * a)
{
    std::cout << a << " (ptr)\n";
}

int main()
{
    const char a[] = "Hello Array!";

    foo(a); // Prints: "Hello Array! (ptr)"
}
```